# Jasmin sms : Bind failed on smpp-1-ire.smscarrier.com:8011

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, smpp, jasmin-sms

I use **[Jasmin sms Gateway](http://jasmin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/)**, and I have to connect to a server: **smpp-1-ire.smscarrier.com at port 8011**, I following your instructions but I can not connect, all other configurations and test works :

```
Establishing TCP connection to smpp-1-ire.smscarrier.com:8011
2018-04-10 15:24:06 INFO 11188 Connecting to IPv4Address(TCP, 'smpp-1-ire.smscarrier.com', 8011) ...
2018-04-10 15:24:07 WARNING 11188 SMPP connection established from 52.31.169.62 to port 51982
2018-04-10 15:24:07 INFO 11188 Connection made to smpp-1-ire.smscarrier.com:8011
2018-04-10 15:24:07 WARNING 11188 Requesting bind as transceiver
2018-04-10 15:24:07 ERROR 11188 Bind failed [[Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'jasmin.vendor.smpp.pdu.error.SMPPTransactionError'>: ESME_RBINDFA$
]]. Disconnecting...
```

I tried to change the 2275 listening port in 8011 on jasmin.cfg , nothing...

But this works :

- System ID: test
- Password: test
- host: smsc-sim.smscarrier.com
- Port: 2775

Log:

```
*2018-04-10 17:35:21 INFO     14022 Establishing TCP connection to smsc-sim.smscarrier.com:2775
2018-04-10 17:35:21 INFO     14022 Connecting to IPv4Address(TCP, 'smsc-sim.smscarrier.com', 2775) ...
2018-04-10 17:35:21 WARNING  14022 SMPP connection established from 35.177.141.136 to port 48570
2018-04-10 17:35:21 INFO     14022 Connection made to smsc-sim.smscarrier.com:2775
2018-04-10 17:35:21 WARNING  14022 Requesting bind as transceiver*
2018-04-10 17:35:21 WARNING  14022 Bind succeeded...now in state BOUND_TRX
```

Comment: If you cannot bind, that's most probably case when not properly configured at the SMS gateway. I'm not familiar with that gateway, but its probably the same as within the SMSC. Sometimes also System type matters (not just port, systemid and password), and max.number of transceivers,transmitters and receivers, which can bind to.

Answer (score 0):

I am still convinced that Jasmin can be configured with my service provider, but I do not know all [JasminSMS](http://jasmin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/) settings, as with [NowSMS](https://www.nowsms.com/) it worked, and that I used for tests, I took a [screenshot of the configuration](http://www.exonet3i.com/img/nowsms-config1.jpg), if someone one can help me find the 2 parameters that are missing, **systype smpp** which is accepted but also maybe **SMSC Character Set** whose value should be: IA5 (GSM).

JasminSMS Gateway is perhaps not compatible with this provider, it would still be extraordinary, given the notoriety of Jasmin.

Anyway, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest improving logging where you got error response to your SMPP bind request, print request parameters and response error code. Have a look at [SMPP specification](http://opensmpp.org/specs/smppv50.pdf) as well to see the meaning of the error code. Potential reasons :

- At least one of the following parameter values are wrong: system_id, system_type or password.
- Your bind requestor origin host IP is not white listed on SMPP server side.
- SMPP server side might be refusing 2nd client bind using the same system_id.
- Address Range parameter usage might have been enforced by SMPP serve
- There can be system_id or password character length limitation on your API side